# Compress and upload image using python-flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, image-upload

I am using Python-flask application for image processing, however, the image compression is done in JavaScript and then upload is being done in python flask backend, when I try to access the image in python method via request.args.get('image'), its giving **None** details as below

```js
var img = $('#img-upload')[0];
    function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('#img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
          img.onload = function() {
              alert("Image is loaded");
              var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
              var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
              var width = img.width;
              var height = img.height;

              if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                  height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                  width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
              } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                  width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                  height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
              }

              var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              canvas.width = width;
              canvas.height = height;
              canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);
              var newImageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 30/100);
              var result_image_obj = new Image();
              result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
              console.log(result_image_obj.src);
              console.log("Starting Upload...");

              if (result_image_obj.src == "") {
                  alert("You must load an image and compress it first!");
                  return false;
              }
              var callback= function(response){
                  console.log("image uploaded successfully! :)");
                  console.log(response);          
              }
              $.ajax({
                  url:"/users/api/v1/uploadimage",
                  type:'POST',
                  data:{'image':result_image_obj},
                  cache:false,
                  processData:false,
                  contentType:false,
                  error:function(){
                      console.log("upload error")
                  },
                  success:function(data){
                      console.log(data)
                      console.log("upload success")
                  }
              })
              console.log("Completed Upload...");
          }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="/updateuser" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp"/>
        <img id="img-upload" name="img-upload" src="#"/>
</form>
```

The problem Im facing is I'm not able to get the image in python flask via request.args.get, what am I doing wrong ? Pls suggest. python code as below

```
@app.route('/users/api/v1/uploadimage',methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadimage():
    print "In uploadimage()"
    try:
        file = request.args.get('image')
        print "Filename",file
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
        return "True";
```

Comment: please take a look on this http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: Thanks for edit & help. I am not getting image argument in python that i am passing in ajax call. What i am doing wrong? Pls suggest.

Comment: In flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads link we are accepting argument of <input> tag, but in my case i need compressed image object. How can i get this in python?

Comment: Or On the other hand, How can i set this compressed object to something else so that i can access this in python? Pls Suggest.

Comment: wait , have worked on this i have a suggestion! you will have to save an image in your server right?@VinayakMahajan

Answer (score 3):

> Its working for me to Compress and Upload Image.

```js
function readFile(evt) {
     var file = evt.target.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     output_format = "jpg";
     reader.onload = function(event) {
         var i = document.getElementById("source_image");
             i.src = event.target.result;
             i.onload = function(){
                 image_width=$(i).width(),
                 image_height=$(i).height();

                 if(image_width > image_height){
                     i.style.width="320px";
                 }else{
                     i.style.height="300px";
                 }
                 i.style.display = "block";
                 console.log("Image loaded");
             }
     };

     console.log("Filename:" + file.name);
     console.log("Filesize:" + (parseInt(file.size) / 1024) + " Kb");
     console.log("Type:" + file.type);
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);

     return false;
 }
 
  $( "#upload" ).click(function() {
        var source_image = document.getElementById('source_image');
        if (source_image.src == "") {
            alert("You must load an image first!");
            return false;
        }

        var quality = 30;
        
        console.log("process start...");
        var time_start = new Date().getTime();
        output_format = "jpg";
        console.log("process start compress ...");
     source_image.src = jic.compress(source_image,quality,output_format).src;
     console.log('Compressed in: ' + new Date().getTime() - time_start + 'ms');

     var successCallback= function(response){
            console.log("image uploaded successfully! :)");
            console.log(response);       
        }

        var errorCallback= function(response){
            console.log("image Filed to upload! :)");
            console.log(response); 
        }
     
     var time_start = new Date().getTime();
     console.log("process start upload ...");
     jic.upload(source_image, '/uploadimage', 'file', 'new.jpg',successCallback,errorCallback);
     console.log('uploaded in: ' + new Date().getTime() - time_start + 'ms');
     
    });

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_form" action="/updateuser" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Choose file</label>
  <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
  <img id="source_image">
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="uploadimage">
</form>
<script src="https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C/blob/master/src/JIC.js"></script>
```

> Python Code

```
def uploadimage():
    print "In uploadimage() trying to upload"
    try:
        file = request.files['file']
        print "File",file
        print "Name",file.filename
    except Exception as e:
        print "Failed",str(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okey, 
Let me correct some problem I found with your code!

First, you need to use [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) from javascript in order to send bytes data to the server (your compressed image ) in this case.
to do that I have added the following code :

```
console.log("Starting Upload...");
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("fileToUpload", result_image_obj.src);
```

and now you can easily now send it via  ajax :

```
$.ajax({
                  url:"/users/api/v1/uploadimage",
                  type:'POST',
                  data:formData,
                  processData: false, // important
                  contentType: false, // important
                  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                  error:function(){
                      console.log("upload error")
                  },
                  success:function(data){
                      console.log(data)
                      console.log("upload success")
                  }
              })
```

Note That you have to send the formData object as parameter of data in your ajax and with enctype : 'multipart/form-data'.

Now in your flask server use this code :

```
@app.route('/users/api/v1/uploadimage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadimage():
    """
    this will try to upload an image
    """
    print "In uploadimage()"
    try:
        a_file = request.get_data(cache=False, as_text=False, parse_form_data=False)
        print "Filename", a_file
    except Exception as exce:
        print str(exce)
        return "True"
    return "oke"
```

as said in [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data) 
the  get_data method

> This reads the buffered incoming data from the client into one
>   bytestring. By default this is cached but that behavior can be changed
>   by setting cache to False

now the second problem is to find how to save that string-byte file as an image on your server :

**still looking how to do that** will add it soon.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Yes, but i unable to convert this into image format, So i started to use JIC library https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C. with this one i am getting the image object in python but image that i compressed is getting corrupted due to some reason.